# ERROR:`data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not an S3 object with class reactiveExpr/reactive

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to build a Corona Dashboard. Where If someone selects State from the dropdown, District wise cases to be displayed in the graph. E.g. If someone selects Gujarat, it shows district wise cases in Bar chart. Someone change it to Maharashtra, It should update with the district of Maharashtra.
But I am getting **"ERROR:`data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not an S3 object with class reactiveExpr/reactive**" error.

```
library(shiny)
library(readxl)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Corona Data"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput(inputId = "state", 
                        label = "Select the State",
                        choices = unique(data$`Detected State`))
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
           plotOutput("stateplot")
        )
    )
)


data <- read_excel("Live Data Worldometer.xlsx", sheet = "IndiaData")
data <- data[,c(-2,-1)]

server <- function(session, input, output) {

    d1 <- reactive({data %>% group_by(`Detected State`) %>% count(`Detected District`) %>% filter(`Detected State` == input$state)
        })

    output$stateplot <- renderPlot({
        ggplot(d1, aes(d1$`Detected District`, d1$n))+geom_bar(stat = "identity")
    })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[This is the output I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPn8j.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`d1` is not a dataframe but an expression that needs to be evaluated (`reactive` does not return a dataframe). You need to active the reactive element before using it in `ggplot2`

```r
server <- function(session, input, output) {

    d1 <- reactive({
        data %>% group_by(`Detected State`) %>% 
                 count(`Detected District`) %>%
                 filter(`Detected State` == input$state)
        })

    output$stateplot <- renderPlot({
        ggplot(d1(), aes(x = `Detected District`, y = n)) +
             geom_bar(stat = "identity")
    })

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried with correction in code as suggested by you. But getting following error. **Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)**

Comment: Sorry, I had not see your already add an object called `data`: it was at the same time input and output in your `reactive`. Could you try again with the edited solution ? (renamed object)

Comment: you need to call d1() *inside* `renderPlot` (inside a reactive Context).

Comment: Wow. Kudos to you. Thank you so much. It works perfectly fine. Once again Thank thank thank you so much.

Comment: Nice ! And thanks to @shosaco for the debugging. Could you accept the answer since it suits you ? (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for guidelines if needed).